# Use a single Redux reducer for all CRUD actions?

Tags: redux, ngrx

Why not use a single reducer function to add, update, and remove entities to/from a Redux store?  It could simply use an action.payload.table property to identify the proper "table" to use in the store.

I've never seen this pattern in examples, blog posts, etc.  On the contrary, most examples have actions dedicated to toggling a single field on an entity, such as a "completed" flag on a todo.  The amount of repetition that would require in a large app has kept me from using Redux, so I hope this is doable.

For example:

```
function entityReducer(state, action) {

  //Action payload includes the entity "type" or "table" name

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_ENTITY': {
      ...
    }
    case 'UPDATE_ENTITY': {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually that's the way you structure a reducer, and it will still require 4 actions :) Look at MobX, might me more to your taste.

Comment: @OriDrori does MobX provide generic CRUD reducer for objects? it was not clear for me after having a quick look at MobX

Comment: @ciekawy - MobX is another state manager. It's not a reducer.

Comment: @OriDrori as the question was in particular regarding a reusable CRUD reducer I was wondering how MobX can help with this

Comment: @ciekawy - I was referring to this part of the question - "The amount of repetition that would require in a large app has kept me from using Redux", as MobX requires less boilerplate.

Comment: got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's perfectly viable.  I actually have something similar in my production app, where I pass along `itemType`, `itemID`, and possibly `newItemAttributes` fields in the action as needed.  That said, I also use [Redux-ORM](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) as an abstraction layer for handling updates within those reducers.  I've written [a couple posts about using Redux-ORM](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/practical-redux-part-1-redux-orm-basics/) on my blog.

You may also be interested in the [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section in the Redux docs, which talks about ways to reuse reducer logic.

Comment: Glad to hear this is viable.  Why do nearly all examples include an action that updates a single field on a single entity?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write those examples :)  Probably for the same reason that most framework demos are another TodoMVC implementation - it's simple and shows off the basic ideas.